# Can you change the runtime on an encrypted phone (KitKat)?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, encryption, nexus-5, art

Nexus 5 owner here.

Basically, I encrypted my phone a while back while on Dalvik Runtime and recently wanted to give ART a try again (to check app compatibility).

The problem is that when I set ART as the default runtime and reboot, it doesn't try to apply to change and reverts back to Dalvik. [it worked fine prior to encryption]. Is this a known/common occurrence (search engines didn't give me much)?

Thanks!

Comment: Decrypt the device, convert to ART, then re-encrypt again?

Comment: Once encrypted you can't decrypt the volume again.

Comment: Yeah, the only way to decrypt is a reset IIRC. Pretty odd that there's no clean way to change the runtime when encrypted though...

Comment: I would be inclined to think that the encryption and therefore, encrypted apps and their runtime are dalvikvm based, hence switching to ART will not work as its entirely different, apps are the same but underneath the runtime engine's bonnet - different. On the next release of Android, this will be default - ART that is, and would expect the same thing to happen that you're experiencing, in the exact opposite - ART and encrypted device, switching to DalvikVM will revert back to ART.

Comment: Do you have installed Xposed?

Comment: A small comment on the check compatibility thing: please note that the experimental version of art provided in kitkat and the stable version used in Lollipop differ a lot. So if the whole purpose of your question is that you want to check your apps for compatibility before upgrading to Lollipop, this might not be reliably possible.